Bold QLabel font with PyQt6 from ui file
I have upgraded from PyQt5 to PyQt6 (Qt version: 6.7.1) and noticed a change how bold fonts are rendered in QLabels.
I typically load a ui file generated from Qt Designer directly with:
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, uic
# ...
self.ui = uic.loadUi("main.ui")

where the code for the label has not changed:
<widget class="QLabel" name="label">
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            <weight>75</weight>
            <bold>true</bold>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>Plot Control</string>
          </property>
         </widget>

The implementation for PyQt5 looks like this:

while the implementation for PyQt6 looks like this:

How do I need to adjust the ui designer file to actually make the label font bold when using PyQt6?
Note: I am aware that I could change self.ui.label.setStyleSheet("font-weight: bold") but I'd prefer to have the styling done in the ui file.

This is a Qt issue, not a Python one. What Qt (not PyQt) version do you actually have? What font are you using? Have you checked with other fonts? It seems similar to QTBUG-94781, but it was marked as resolved at least for 6.1/6.2/6.3 onwards. Qt 6.6/6.7 introduced some changes in font rendering, though, so it may be a regression.

I am on Qt version 6.7.1 and use the standard "MS Shell Dlg 2" font family. Even with other fonts, the problem persists. It being a regression sounds like a reasonable explanation to me.

Does the problem happen in Designer too (running in Qt6, not Qt5)?

This was a good hint! I opened and saved the ui file in the  designer running Qt6 - I admit, I had not pulled down the new version, yet. Turns out, if the <weight>75</weight> is deleted, it works as expected.

Good to know. I suggest you to post your own answer, and consider filing a bug report on bugreports.qt.io.

After the upgrade from Qt5 to Qt6, the attribute
<weight>75</weight>

needs to be removed in the ui file for the font to render in bold. As suggested by @musicamante, a bug report has been filed: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-126087
